# Поиск на сайте по нескольким ключевым словам Yii2

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

Не могу найти статей как можно сделать безболезненный поиск по сайту по двум ключевым например словам в поиске
Сделал вот так через like но это не совсем то что мне нужно
КОД: ВЫДЕЛИТЬ ВСЁ

```
public function search($params) {

    $query = CatNomenclature::find();


    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
    ]);

    $this->load($params);




    if (!$this->validate()) {
        // uncomment the following line if you do not want to return any records when validation fails
        // $query->where('0=1');
        return $dataProvider;
    }

    if ($this->search) {
        $query->orFilterWhere(['like', 'id', $this->search])
                ->orFilterWhere(['like', 'name', $this->search]);

    }

    return $dataProvider;
}
```

У меня например есть такое значение в БД
"Аккумулятор для Apple iPad Air 2 Orig"
"Аккумулятор для Apple iPhone 4 Copy"
и я хочу получить результат поиска по словам **Аккумулятор iPad** . Как мне это сделать?
БД MySQL

Comment: Для поиска очень хорошо использовать elasticsearch. В yii2 есть готовое расширение для работы с ним.

Comment: @fedornabilkin Полностью согласен на счёт использования Elasticsearch

Answer (score 1):

Самый простой способ разбить запрос по словам и искать как вы и делали с помощью лайка:

```
if ($this->search) {
    $words = explode(' ', $this->search);
    foreach ($words as $word) {
        $query->andWhere(['like', 'name', $word]);
    }

}
```

Если вы хотите не точное совпадение, поиск по корням и тому подобное, то надо использовать специальные поисковые движки, которые это умеют, например elasticsearch.